# how to display manytomanyfields in django admin

Tags: django, admin, manytomanyfield

I add a likes field in my item models and would like to display all likes against each item in the admin panel. How I can do that currently is what my code looks like. I am getting this error:**'User' object has no attribute 'likes'**

Model:

```
likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')
```

Admin.py

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','author','item_category','date','get_products')
    list_filter = ('item_category',)

    def get_products(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([p.likes for p in obj.likes.all()])
```

Comment: That's because `related_name='blog_posts'`. Change the `related_name` to something like `user_likes`. Then you can get the likes with `user.user_likes.all()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made changes in my model and update the related name. Since i am new i apprecite if you guide where i am wrong. Below is my udpated code admin.py

Comment: class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','author','item_category','date','get_products')
    list_filter = ('item_category',)

    def get_products(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([p.likes for p in obj.user.user_likes.all()])